# Poor anti-aliasing on extreme rotation

Tags: css, svg, transform

I'm rotating an SVG over the X axis with this code:

```
img {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(80deg)
}
```

The stars in the SVG end up looking very pixelated: http://codepen.io/maxedison/pen/zGOyRO

Is there any way to improve the anti-aliasing? I'm seeing this in both Chrome & Firefox. I tried setting `backface-visibility: hidden` but that made no difference. I have also tried this with a JPG of the flag image rather than an SVG and the same problem occurs there as well.

Comment: It doesn't matter that the source is an SVG. If you transform the `<img>` you are transforming the bitmap representation of the SVG image, not the vector version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's a nice question. Honnestly I can't think of a good solution for you here. The only "trick" that pops out of my mind is to blur your image ?

```
-webkit-filter: blur(0.8px);
```

And for the rendering mode of the image to optimizeQuality ?

Here is my solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGzVjd

Comment: Btw, it seems that the stars on the initial image are already pixelated.

Comment: The image is SVG, it's not pixels. It does not look pixelated on Chrome http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg

Comment: yes you're right because you have 100% scale here. Thus if you resize it (height or width), it will be a bit pixelated ;). Even without resizing, it looks pixelated while using the perspective. Well easy solution, blur to removes those useless details.